# HTML and CSS navigation bar next to logo

Tags: html, css, navbar

I'm new to programming and I'm trying to make a website but I have a big problem. I want a navigation bar next to my logo and sticking to the top when i scroll, but I can't get it to work. The text is on top of each other and I don't know how to make it work.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <style>
         body{   background-color: black}
         img.logo{   margin-left: 20px;
         margin-top: 10px;}
         li{ display: inline}
         a{  position: fixed;
         width: auto;
         height: 50px;
         margin-left: 50px;
         margin-top: 60px;
         color: #DFDD7D;
         font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
         font-size: 20px; 
         font-weight: 300;
         letter-spacing: 0.5px
         margin: 0px;
         padding: px;}
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <header>
         <img class="logo" src="https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/7zZpeNiaANxK7CqDKwE2PdemWJFKoskKGKelsSmQSNmZQOBpKwMkOST3ucML162QIf3k5_ZclpFT_PE=w998-h1006" style="height: auto; width: 300px" >
         <li><a href="Site%20DIA%20main.html">Projecten</a></li>
         <li><a href="">over</a></li>
      </header>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to the world of web development!

The first order of business is to fix your CSS so it is valid. We'll also tidy it up a little.

1. Add a semicolon after `letter-spacing: 0.5px`
2. You don't have any value assigned to `padding: px;` so just remove that line
3. It's not necessarily invalid, but I would remove the declarations for `margin-left` and `margin-top` on the `a` element because you are overriding them with `margin: 0px;` later on.

With that done, the CSS should look like this:

```
body {
  background-color: black;
}

img.logo {
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

li {
  display: inline;
}

a {
  position: fixed;
  width: auto;
  height: 50px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-top: 60px;
  color: #DFDD7D;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 300;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
}
```

Now, lets make the HTML valid and tidy it up, as well.

1. You can't have `<li>` elements directly under `<header>`. They only go inside `<ol>` or `<ul>` elements. `<ul>` (unordered list) makes the most sense here, so let's use that.
2. It's a good idea to place a value in the `href` attribute of your `<a>` element. If you're just prototyping and don't have a URL to use, yet, people typically use `#`.

The HTML now looks like this:

```
<header>
  <img class="logo" src="https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/7zZpeNiaANxK7CqDKwE2PdemWJFKoskKGKelsSmQSNmZQOBpKwMkOST3ucML162QIf3k5_ZclpFT_PE=w998-h1006" style="height: auto; width: 300px" >

  <ul>
    <li><a href="Site%20DIA%20main.html">Projecten</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">over</a></li>
  </ul>
</header>
```

Now, one issue is that you are applying a fixed position to each of your `<a>` elements separately. What you actually want to do is apply a fixed position to the whole navbar (the whole `<ul>`). So change your CSS like so:

```
ul {
    position: fixed;
}

a {
  width: auto;
  height: 50px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-top: 60px;
  color: #DFDD7D;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 300;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
}
```

This is just an excerpt. But notice that I moved `position: fixed;` from `a` to `ul`. Really, that is all that's needed. If you want to fine tune where the navbar appears, go ahead and use `top` and `left` like so:

```
ul {
  position: fixed;
  top: 5px;
  left: 10px;
}
```

The whole page now looks like this:

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

img.logo {
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

li {
  display: inline;
}

ul {
  position: fixed;
  top: 5px;
  left: 10px;
}

a {
  width: auto;
  height: 50px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-top: 60px;
  color: #DFDD7D;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 300;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <img class="logo" src="https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/7zZpeNiaANxK7CqDKwE2PdemWJFKoskKGKelsSmQSNmZQOBpKwMkOST3ucML162QIf3k5_ZclpFT_PE=w998-h1006" style="height: auto; width: 300px" >

  <ul>
    <li><a href="Site%20DIA%20main.html">Projecten</a></li>
    <li><a href="">over</a></li>
  </ul>
</header>
```

Answer (score 1):

`<li>` elements should be in a `<ul>` or `<ol>`

In the example below, I used flexboxes for the layout. Please have a look [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) to learn about flexboxes.

```css
body {
  background-color: black
}

header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
}

img.logo {
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

li {
  margin-left: 1em;
}

a {
  color: #DFDD7D;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 300;
  letter-spacing: 0.5px margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <img class="logo" src="http://placehold.it/300x100">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="Site%20DIA%20main.html">Projecten</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">over</a></li>
  </ul>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the position to relative and add "vertical-align:top" to the anchor.

```css
 body{   background-color: black}

    img.logo{   margin-left: 20px;
                margin-top: 10px;}

    li{ display: inline}

    a{  position: relative;
        width: auto;
        height: 50px;
        margin-left: 50px;
        margin-top: 60px;
        color: #DFDD7D;
        font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
        font-size: 20px; 
        font-weight: 300;
        letter-spacing: 0.5px;
        vertical-align:top;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: px;}
```

```html
<img class="logo" src="http://lorempixel.com/300/100" style="height: auto; width: 300px" >

<li><a href="Site%20DIA%20main.html">Projecten</a></li>
<li><a href="">over</a></li>
```

Comment: This is true.  Maybe you meant to post this to OP's initial question?

Answer (score 0):

Put your li in a ul, display li inline-block, then float both the logo and the ul left, or float the ul right and put a margin-right on it if that is what you would prefer.
Make your header fixed and the logo and nav remain at the top while scrolling.

```html
<style>
      body{   background-color: black}

      header#header {
        position: fixed;
        width: 100%;
      }

      div.logo {
        margin-left: 20px;
        margin-top: 10px;
        float: left;
      }

      ul#nav {
        float: left;
      }

      ul#nav li {
        display: inline-block;
      }

      ul#nav li a {
        margin-left: 50px;
        margin-top: 60px;
        color: #DFDD7D;
        font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
        font-size: 20px;
        font-weight: 300;
        letter-spacing: 0.5px;
      }

  </style>

    <header id="header">
    <div class="logo">
      <img class="logo" src="https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/7zZpeNiaANxK7CqDKwE2PdemWJFKoskKGKelsSmQSNmZQOBpKwMkOST3ucML162QIf3k5_ZclpFT_PE=w998-h1006" style="height: auto; width: 300px" >
    </div>
    <nav id="main_nav">
      <ul id="nav">
        <li><a href="Site%20DIA%20main.html">Projecten</a></li>
        <li><a href="">over</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think having `<li>` tags for horizontal links is a bit to complicated for nothing. You could simply use `<a>` tags without the `<li>`. Here is an exemple of how I think would be the best.

[Codepen demo](https://codepen.io/AwkwardFly/pen/rzWBXv)

If you want the content to be scrollable with the navbar on top (without it being fixed), you need to wrap it into a `<div>` too. This also has the very nice effect of allowing you a simple footer, should you eventually want one.

Since you didn't specify any browser support, I took the liberty of using flex to do so.